# Error document.geElementById('id').style.width

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a problem. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="id" style="position:absolute;">
       <img id="0" src="../FileTypes/mat.png" style="position:fixed;top:50px;left:25px;" />       
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xsize = screen.width;
var ysize = screen.height;
document.getElementById('id').style.height = ysize + "px";
document.getElementById('id').style.width = xsize + "px";
</script>
```

And I have following error:[image: Error]

Does anybody know where have I error in my code and how can I repair it? Please help me.

Comment: please update image properly. it is not visible.

Comment: "id" and "0" are horrible names to use as ids. ;)

Comment: I had no problem running your code (chrome), but when are you firing the javascript, maybe before page is loaded?

Comment: Probably that was the problem. I have placed script on the end of the document, and it works! But thank you all. And I'm using 'id' for test sand examples. Siva, the image is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is likely being executed before the DOM has been fully constructed. You should do one of the following:

- use [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)
- use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload)
- place your `script` just before the `</body>` tag